# Nsis: File commmand can't find the file when the path contains variable

Tags: file, nsis

There is my code 

`!define InputDir "D:\a"
!define OutDir "D:\Temp2"
StrCpy $R0 "T1"
SetOutPath "${OutDir}\$R0"
File /r "${InputDir}\$R0\*.*"`

There have two directories T1 T2 in "D:\a".And T1's dir has files in located.
But when I running it ,it showed that "File: D:\a\$R0*.* ->no files found"
Obviously The command can't find the variable.If there any way to get the files when I just konw the var which contain the dir's name? Thanks.

and than

Answer (score 1):

`File` is a hybrid function that executes both at compile-time and run-time!

You cannot use variables with the `File` instruction, only defines:

```
!define srcdir "c:\myfiles"

OutFile Test.exe

Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File /r "${srcdir}\*.*"
SectionEnd
```

Variables are expanded when the installer is running on the end-users machine but the compiler needs to know the file paths when it compresses the files on your local machine.

If you want to do anything special then you must use `!system` to execute a external tool/script that generates your desired instructions that you can `!include`:

```
InstallDir $Temp\InstTest
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

; Build dummy directory tree for this example:
!system 'md %temp%\test\1\2\3\4'
!system 'md %temp%\test\a\b'
!appendfile '$%temp%\test\a\file.txt' "Hello$\n"

; Build batch file
!appendfile "$%temp%\nsistmp.cmd" '@ECHO OFF&SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION$\r$\n'
!appendfile "$%temp%\nsistmp.cmd" 'SET nsh=%~1&SET dst=%~2&GOTO s$\r$\n'
!appendfile "$%temp%\nsistmp.cmd" ':enum$\r$\n'
!appendfile "$%temp%\nsistmp.cmd" 'FOR /D %%A IN ("%~1\%~2\*") DO ((>> "%nsh%" ECHO CreateDirectory "%dst%\%~2\%%~nA") & CALL %0 "%~1" "%~2\%%~nA")$\r$\n'
!appendfile "$%temp%\nsistmp.cmd" '@GOTO :EOF$\r$\n'
!appendfile "$%temp%\nsistmp.cmd" ':s$\r$\n'
!appendfile "$%temp%\nsistmp.cmd" 'CALL :enum "%~3" "."$\r$\n'

; Execute batch and include the result:
Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
!tempfile nsh
!system '"$%temp%\nsistmp.cmd" "${nsh}" $InstDir "%temp%\test"'
!delfile "$%temp%\nsistmp.cmd"
!include "${nsh}"
!delfile "${nsh}"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Yes,I know it .But I  want to pack dirs of InputDir ,just dirs ,no files. So I foreach the InputDir to get dir's name and do pack,which save in variable .I want to know  if there any way or plugin can help me  do it .Thanks!

Comment: Your original question says nothing about only including directories?! Anyway, I added the code to do just that.